# Parsing a name from a complex string in Tableau

Tags: regex, parsing, text, tableau-api

I have a series of values in Tableau that are long strings intermixed with letters and numbers. I am unable to control the data output, but would like to parse the names from these strings. They follow the following format:

- Potato 1TByte 4.5 NFA
- Board 256GByte 553 NCA
- Launch 4 512GByte 4.5 NFA
- Launch 4S 512GByte 4.5 NCA

From each of these, I am attempting to capture the following:

- "Potato"
- "Board"
- "Launch 4"
- "Launch 4S"

Each string follows the same format: the name, followed by size, followed by some extra information we don't really care about.

I've tried to put together some text parsing strings, but am coming up short, and am still trying to learn regular expressions.

The Tableau calculated field I was trying to work with was something like the following:

`LEFT([String], FIND([String], "Byte") - 2)`

The issue is that the text and numbers preceding Byte can be anywhere from 4 to 2 characters and I need a way to identify the length of that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option which uses a regex replacement:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('Launch 4 512GByte 4.5 NFA', ' \d+[A-Z]Byte .*$', '')
```

This strips off everything from the `Byte` term to the right, leaving us with only the product name.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I'll give it a try once I figure out a workaround for the fact that regular expressions can't be used when connected to a SQL server.

Comment: I think you can use regular expressions if you first make an extract. The fields based on regular expressions won't be accessible when you disable the extract, but will when be once again when you re-enable the extract. At least that's how it worked prior to hyper.

Comment: REGEXP_EXTRACT() can be simpler than replace sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following - this seems to work - [Screenshot of Tableau output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ6UW.png). Find below the formulas for the various derived columns you see in the screenshot (Your source column is called **[Name]**)

1. Step1 = `LEFT([Name],FIND([Name],"Byte")-1)`
2. Step2 = `LEN([Step1])-LEN(REPLACE([Step1]," ",""))`
3. Step3 = `FINDNTH([Step1]," ",[Step2])`
4. Step4 = `LEFT([Step1],[Step3]-1)`

*And of course you can nest all these in a single calculated field - kept them as separate columns for easier understanding*